# how to use data binder inside anchor tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have anchor tag in asp.net repetor I want to be to embed data binder to add to href to create light-box

> error  Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> <a href="editReminders.aspx?reminderID=<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, >"ReminderID") %>" shape="rect" > class="extLink">Edite</a>
> ```

Comment: I dont think the <% tag is allowed inside the repeater i thought it was <# this one instead. but the line of code you pasted also contains errors and is not well formed i think take a look at you DataBinder.Eval()

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in the code behind by creating a method

```
protected string GetReminderLink(object Data)
{
 return "<a target=\"_BLANK\" href=\"editReminders.aspx?reminderID=" + Data.ToString() + "\";\">Text</a>";
}
```

and then calling it on your asp page as follows

```
<%# GetReminderLink(Eval("ReminderID"))%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='<%#Eval("ReminderID","editReminders.aspx?reminderID={0}") %>' shape="rect" class="extLink">Edite</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<a href='editReminders.aspx?reminderID=<%# Eval("ReminderID") %>' shape="rect" class="extLink">Edite</a>
```